# Erro; A conexão não foi fechada.O estado atual da conexao é aberta SqlServer 2016

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

Estou criando uma aplicação no visual Studio em C#, e ao conectar ao sqlserver no Server Explore, foi tudo correto no teste de conexão.

Essa é minha string de conexão:

```
return "Data Source=DESKTOP-58ASAQP\\MSSQLSERVER16;Initial Catalog=ControleDeEstoque;User ID=sa;Password=root";
```

Porem, ao inserir um dado no formulário me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> "A conexão não foi fechada.O estado atual da conexao é aberta."

Alguém já teve esse erro? 
Isso requer alguma configuração no Sqlserver?

Comment: Dê mais informações sobre seu código, não tem como saber o que você faz so com a mensagem. Você pode estar executando várias ações no banco de forma sequencial e no meio do caminho fecha um conexão que todos usam.

Comment: Boa tarde.Pesquisando meu código, descobri que meu método Incluir não estava desconectando após ser executado.Obg pela atenção....

Answer (score 2):

Isso ocorre simplesmente porque você esta tentando abrir uma conexão com o banco quando ela já esta aberta.

Veja o exemplo abaixo.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

namespace stackoverflow
{
    public partial class ConexaoAberta : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected String ConnString
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"].ToString();
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConnString;

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.Append("SELECT *  FROM [stackoverflow].[dbo].[Categoria]");

            conn.Open();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), conn);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            GetSubCategoria(conn);
        }

        public void GetSubCategoria(SqlConnection conn)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.Append("SELECT * FROM [stackoverflow].[dbo].[SubCategoria]");

            conn.Open(); // Aqui você tenta abri novamente a conexão, sendo que o método acima não tinha
            // fechado ela.
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), conn);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

No ultimo método `public void GetSubCategoria(SqlConnection conn)`, posso minha conexão e tendo abrir ela novamente `conn.Open();` , sendo que o status atual é *open* gerando o erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Certamente seu erro esta sendo gerando quando você tentar inserir seus dados.

Verifique se o status da conexão é open, o mais aconselhável seria envolver todas suas conexões em blocos.

[using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/yh598w02.aspx) .

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_dbconnstr)) 
{
    //code
}
```

Ou [try finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx).

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_dbconnstr);
try
{
    //code
}
finally
{
    conn.Dispose();
}
```